# nginx-ingress k8s on Google no IP address

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I am practicing the `k8s` by following the [ingress chapter](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes/create-kubernetes-ingress-routes). I am using Google Cluster. Specification are as follows

`master`: `1.11.7-gke.4`
`node`: `1.11.7-gke.4`

```sh
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                                   STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION         INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP      OS-IMAGE                             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-1sm3   Ready    <none>   6h    v1.11.7-gke.4   10.148.0.46   35.197.128.107   Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.14.89+         docker://17.3.2
gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-819z   Ready    <none>   6h    v1.11.7-gke.4   10.148.0.47   35.198.217.71    Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.14.89+         docker://17.3.2
gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-djhz   Ready    <none>   6h    v1.11.7-gke.4   10.148.0.45   35.197.159.75    Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.14.89+         docker://17.3.2
```

`master endpoint`: `35.186.148.93`

DNS: `singh.hbot.io` (master IP)

To keep my question short. I post my source code in the snippet and links back to here.

Files:

[`deployment.yaml`](https://gist.github.com/elcolie/ca12ae7f242f4f340488aebec7bae7e8)
[`ingress.yaml`](https://gist.github.com/elcolie/04400ccc8e1250624980d859bf566879)
[`ingress-rules.yaml`](https://gist.github.com/elcolie/19da63c1b0153341a647a032814d4896)

**Problem:**
`curl http://singh.hbot.io/webapp1` got timed out

**Description**

```sh
$ kubectl get deployment -n nginx-ingress
NAME            DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-ingress   1         1         1            0           2h
```

`nginx-ingress` deployment is not available.

```sh
$ kubectl describe deployment -n nginx-ingress
Name:                   nginx-ingress
Namespace:              nginx-ingress
CreationTimestamp:      Mon, 04 Mar 2019 15:09:42 +0700
Labels:                 app=nginx-ingress
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
                        kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                          {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"nginx-ingress","namespace":"nginx-ingress"},"s...
Selector:               app=nginx-ingress
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  1 max unavailable, 1 max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:           app=nginx-ingress
  Service Account:  nginx-ingress
  Containers:
   nginx-ingress:
    Image:       nginx/nginx-ingress:edge
    Ports:       80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-config
      -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-server-secret
    Environment:
      POD_NAMESPACE:   (v1:metadata.namespace)
      POD_NAME:        (v1:metadata.name)
    Mounts:           <none>
  Volumes:            <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   nginx-ingress-77fcd48f4d (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

**pods:**

```sh
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces=true
NAMESPACE       NAME                                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default         webapp1-7d67d68676-k9hhl                          1/1     Running            0          6h
default         webapp2-64d4844b78-9kln5                          1/1     Running            0          6h
default         webapp3-5b8ff7484d-zvcsf                          1/1     Running            0          6h
kube-system     event-exporter-v0.2.3-85644fcdf-xxflh             2/2     Running            0          6h
kube-system     fluentd-gcp-scaler-8b674f786-gvv98                1/1     Running            0          6h
kube-system     fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-srzc2                          2/2     Running            0          6h
kube-system     fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-w2z2q                          2/2     Running            0          6h
kube-system     fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-z7p9l                          2/2     Running            0          6h
kube-system     heapster-v1.6.0-beta.1-5685746c7b-kd4mn           3/3     Running            0          6h
kube-system     kube-dns-6b98c9c9bf-6p8qr                         4/4     Running            0          6h
kube-system     kube-dns-6b98c9c9bf-pffpt                         4/4     Running            0          6h
kube-system     kube-dns-autoscaler-67c97c87fb-gbgrs              1/1     Running            0          6h
kube-system     kube-proxy-gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-1sm3   1/1     Running            0          6h
kube-system     kube-proxy-gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-819z   1/1     Running            0          6h
kube-system     kube-proxy-gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-djhz   1/1     Running            0          6h
kube-system     l7-default-backend-7ff48cffd7-trqvx               1/1     Running            0          6h
kube-system     metrics-server-v0.2.1-fd596d746-bvdfk             2/2     Running            0          6h
kube-system     tiller-deploy-57c574bfb8-xnmtj                    1/1     Running            0          1h
nginx-ingress   nginx-ingress-77fcd48f4d-rfwbk                    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   35         2h
```

**describe pod**

```sh
$ kubectl describe pods -n nginx-ingress
Name:               nginx-ingress-77fcd48f4d-5rhtv
Namespace:          nginx-ingress
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-djhz/10.148.0.45
Start Time:         Mon, 04 Mar 2019 17:55:00 +0700
Labels:             app=nginx-ingress
                    pod-template-hash=3397804908
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.48.2.10
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/nginx-ingress-77fcd48f4d
Containers:
  nginx-ingress:
    Container ID:  docker://5d3ee9e2bf7a2060ff0a96fdd884a937b77978c137df232dbfd0d3e5de89fe0e
    Image:         nginx/nginx-ingress:edge
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://nginx/nginx-ingress@sha256:16c1c6dde0b904f031d3c173e0b04eb82fe9c4c85cb1e1f83a14d5b56a568250
    Ports:         80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-config
      -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-server-secret
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Mon, 04 Mar 2019 18:16:33 +0700
      Finished:     Mon, 04 Mar 2019 18:16:33 +0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  9
    Environment:
      POD_NAMESPACE:  nginx-ingress (v1:metadata.namespace)
      POD_NAME:       nginx-ingress-77fcd48f4d-5rhtv (v1:metadata.name)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from nginx-ingress-token-zvcwt (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  nginx-ingress-token-zvcwt:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  nginx-ingress-token-zvcwt
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From                                           Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----                                           -------
  Normal   Scheduled  26m                  default-scheduler                              Successfully assigned nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-77fcd48f4d-5rhtv to gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-djhz
  Normal   Created    25m (x4 over 26m)    kubelet, gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-djhz  Created container
  Normal   Started    25m (x4 over 26m)    kubelet, gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-djhz  Started container
  Normal   Pulling    24m (x5 over 26m)    kubelet, gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-djhz  pulling image "nginx/nginx-ingress:edge"
  Normal   Pulled     24m (x5 over 26m)    kubelet, gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-djhz  Successfully pulled image "nginx/nginx-ingress:edge"
  Warning  BackOff    62s (x112 over 26m)  kubelet, gke-singh-default-pool-a69fa545-djhz  Back-off restarting failed container
```

**Fix container terminated**
Add to the [`command`](https://serverfault.com/questions/924243/back-off-restarting-failed-container-error-syncing-pod-in-minikube) to `ingress.yaml` to prevent `container` finish running and get terminated by `k8s`.
`command: [ "/bin/bash", "-ce", "tail -f /dev/null" ]`

`Ingress` has no `IP` address from GKE. Let me have a look in details

**describe ingress:**

```sh
$ kubectl describe ing
Name:             webapp-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.48.0.8:8080)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *
        /webapp1   webapp1-svc:80 (<none>)
        /webapp2   webapp2-svc:80 (<none>)
                   webapp3-svc:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"webapp-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"webapp1-svc","servicePort":80},"path":"/webapp1"},{"backend":{"serviceName":"webapp2-svc","servicePort":80},"path":"/webapp2"},{"backend":{"serviceName":"webapp3-svc","servicePort":80}}]}}]}}

Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From                     Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----                     -------
  Warning  Translate  7m45s (x59 over 4h20m)  loadbalancer-controller  error while evaluating the ingress spec: service "default/webapp1-svc" is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"; service "default/webapp2-svc" is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"; service "default/webapp3-svc" is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"
```

From this line I got all the ultimate solution from `Christian Roy` Thank you very much.

**Fix the `ClusterIP`**
It is default value then I have to edit my manifest file using `NodePort` as follow

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp1-svc
  labels:
    app: webapp1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: webapp1
```

And that is.

Comment: Try `kubectl -n nginx-ingress logs nginx-ingress-77fcd48f4d-5rhtv` and see why the container is crashing.

Comment: @roychri Thank you for your comment. I have updated my problem. Right now crashing is fixed. However the ultimate goal is not. Ingres is not routing the request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in your question. The describe of your ingress shows the problem.

You did `kubectl describe ing` and the last part of that output was:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From                     Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----                     -------
  Warning  Translate  7m45s (x59 over 4h20m)  loadbalancer-controller  error while evaluating the ingress spec: service "default/webapp1-svc" is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"; service "default/webapp2-svc" is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"; service "default/webapp3-svc" is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"
```

The important part is:

> error while evaluating the ingress spec: service "default/webapp1-svc" is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"

**Solution**

Just change all your services to be of type `NodePort` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What should I do with my manifest files. I knew that I have to change it. But I still finding the command reference of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have to add [command](http://command:%20[%20%22/bin/bash%22,%20%22-ce%22,%20%22tail%20-f%20/dev/null%22%20]) in order to let the container not finish working.

`command: [ "/bin/bash", "-ce", "tail -f /dev/null" ]`